# Boost/Array.hpp: No such file or directory (On Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019

I have included the boost library by going to properties, and then adding the path in the VC++ include directory, and the C/C++ Additional Include Libraries.

I have added the header files using `#include<boost/array.hpp>` and `#include<boost/static_assert.hpp>`.

While building, I get warnings regarding the other Boost header files, such as `clang.hpp`, however, the error message displayed is `boost/array.hpp: No such file or directory`. Since the warning messages are generated for the other Boost header files, I am assuming that the path has been registered and the Boost files are located by Visual Studio (I am quite possibly wrong about this). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I was building a Linux Console Application, and found out my mistake. Have added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying to build on a linux machine remotely (Crucial detail that I had missed out earlier), so I had to insert the path in the format -I "path", to the boost library on the linux machine. I made the mistake of downloading the boost files on the windows machine, and adding the path to the windows boost files instead.

Go to Properties, C/C++, Command Line (Additional Options), and then enter the path over there to the library on the linux machine.

For example: -I /usr/FileSystem/boost_1_72_0